# `make: * No rule to make target` compile time error

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran, lapack

I am trying to link Lapack library with my Makefile and Fortran 90 code (gfortran), but every time I type : `make pkr_test` (`pkr_test` is the name of the code)
I get the following error :

`make[1]: * No rule to make target '/usr/ben/models/common/src/fitting.o'. Stop. 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/ben/models/common/src' 
Makefile:20: recipe for target '/usr/ben/models/common/src/fitting.o' failed 
make: * [/usr/ben/models/common/src/fitting.o] Error 2`

I can attach the Makefile and the Makefile. In case it will help you to give me a quick solution. I actually tried to attach it but I didn't manage.

Here is the Makefile:

```
#
# Makefile for pqr_test
#
include ../../Makefile.in
#
MODS=   $(DIR_test)wrt_two.o \
    $(DIR_test)ppt_one.o \
    $(DIR_test)cat_one.o \
    $(DIR_test)uti_test.o \
    $(DIR_test)ncdf_test.o \
    $(DIR_test)quick_test.o \
    $(DIR_test)ovr_one.o \
    $(DIR_test)row_to.o \ 
    $(DIR_test)fitting.o 
#
OBJS=pqr_test.o 
#
$(MODS) : 
    cd $(DIR_test) && make $(MODS)
#
pqr_test : $(MODS) $(OBJS)
    cd $(DIR_test) && make $(MODS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -L$(XML_LIB)  -L$(NC_LIB_LOC) -L$(NC_LIB_LAPACK_LOC) -I$(NC_INCLUDE) -I$(NC_LAPACK_INCLUDE) \
        -Wl,-rpath,$(NC_LIB_LOC) $(NC_LIB_LAPACK_LOC) $(MODS) $(OBJS) $(NC_LIB) $(NC_LIB_LAPACK) \
        -lflib -o ../bin/pqr_test
#
pqr_test.o : pqr_test.f90
    cd $(DIR_test) && make $(MODS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -I$(DIR_test) -I$(XML_INCLUDE) -I$(NC_INCLUDE) -I$(NC_LAPACK_INCLUDE) -c pqr_test.f90
#
cleanup:
    mv $(DIR_test)*.o   $(DIR_test)../obj/
    mv $(DIR_test)*.mod $(DIR_test)../mod/
    mv *.o ../obj/
#
clean:
    rm -f $(DIR_test)*.o   
    rm -f $(DIR_test)../obj/*.o 
    rm -f $(DIR_test)*.mod
    rm -f $(DIR_test)../obj/*.o
    rm -f *.o  
    rm -f ../obj/*.o
#
```

Comment: how can I attach the file ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to link Lapack library with my `Makefile` and Fortran 90 code (gfortran), but every time I type : `make pkr_test` (`pkr_test` is the name of the code) I get the following error :

```
make[1]: * No rule to make target '/usr/ben/models/common/src/fitting.o'. Stop. 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/ben/models/common/src' 
Makefile:20: recipe for target '/usr/ben/models/common/src/fitting.o' failed 
make: * [/usr/ben/models/common/src/fitting.o] Error 2
```

The Makefile tries to build the (object) modules specified in `MODS` variable, including the last one, `$(DIR_test)fitting.o`.

It does this by doing the equivalent of calling itself, `make $(DIR_test)fitting.o`. The problem is that your Makefile, and the included Makefile (`../../Makefile.in`) don't include instructions on how to generate that file, and the [implicit make rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) don't success either.

As the dependency (`$(DIR_test)fitting.o`) cannot be built, make cannot build your specified target (`pkr_test`).

Comment: Hi Mctylr, I am a newbie, so I am trying to understand but am not sure I got it, can you tell me explicitly what I need to do exactly to solve this issue ?

Comment: I noticed something else, I discovered that the lapack library is not in the same directory as the main directory DIR_test, any idea how to link it to try to solve this issue, it might be the problem, I think. to be more specific, the lapack library exists in this directory : /usr/lib64/liblapack.a
do you think, this might be the problem ? if yes can you please suggest a solution while using makefile ?

Comment: I also forgot to say that fitting.o is the code that calls the lapack library